# Maps between direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If I have $k$-vector spaces $U,V,W,X$, is every linear map $f:U\oplus V\to W\oplus X$ of the form $f_1 + f_2$ where $f_1:U\to W$ and $f_2:V\to X$? It is true if I consider $f_i$ having images in $W\oplus X$, both.

If I consider these direct sums as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading, i.e. I have $f$ being a map of super-vector spaces, then this should be true, shouldn't it? (Because in the category of super-vector spaces we only consider even maps.)

Comment: Note that you have more assumptions in the second paragraph than the first. Namely, if $f:V\to W$ is a morphism of super-vector spaces, then you (parenthetically) assume that $f(V_0)\subset W_0$, etc.

Comment: For the general question, certainly no: $\hom_k(U\oplus V,W\oplus X)$ is isomorphic to $$\hom_k(U,W)\oplus \hom_k(U,X)\oplus \hom_k(V,W)\oplus\hom_k(V,X)$$ in matricial form, this would look like a decomposition in blocks $$\begin{pmatrix}\hom_k(U,W)&\hom_k(V,W)\\ \hom_k(U,X)&\hom_k(V,X)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @DavidHill Yes, that was the reason why I thought the second paragraph is true. Isn't it true?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli But my last phrase in the first paragraph is true, isn't it?

Comment: You have assumed in the second paragraph that $f:V\to W$ is of the form $f_0+f_1: V_0\oplus V_1 \to W_0\oplus W_1$ so it is true. But, of course, the more general statement is false.

Comment: But $f$ would be automatically of this form if I consider it to be an even parity map, wouldn't it?